# Does the group of homeomorphisms of the hilbert cube have automatic continuity

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, automatic-continuity

A topological group is said to have automatic continuity if every homomorphism from  it to a second countable topological group is continuous. Various topological groups are known to have this property including $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{N}), \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ and $\operatorname{Homeo}(\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}})$.

Is it known if $\operatorname{Homeo}([0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}})$ has this property (with respect to the compact-open topology)?